# temporal median in video

Tags: python, video-processing, median

I have a video file for which I want to calculate the median of the whole sequence using Python. This is, take the median value for each pixel along all frames.

I guess one option is loading the entire video into memory as a multidimensional array (width, height, frames, channels) and then calculating the median using numpy methods.

But, I don't want to reinvent the wheel... there must be something already usable in a library. Also, it would be great if I could avoid loading the video in memory, as some of the files can be quite large.

More specifically, can you suggest an alternative using a tool designed for image analysis or computer vision (e.g. openCV)?